# How to fix Obj Folder Assembly Error: "Executables cannot be satellite assemblies; culture should always be empty"

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, .net-assembly, cultureinfo

### Here's what I've added in the code that makes me experience this error:

I'm using VSCode.

In StartUp.cs - ConfigureServices

```
services.AddLocalization (options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.AddMvc ().SetCompatibilityVersion (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddViewLocalization (LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
```

In StartUp.cs - Configure

```
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};

localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

I've created the Resource file in this folder:

> Resources
>
> > Views
> >
> > > Grants
> > >
> > > > **Index.en-US.resx**
> > > >
> > > > Index.hu-HU.resx

And called the values in this view:

> View
>
> > Grants
> >
> > > **Index.cshtml**

### Problem:

When I build the project, I got an error on the newly created OBJ folder in xxx.Resources.cs file, "Executables cannot be satellite assemblies; culture should always be empty"

> obj
>
> > Debug
> >
> > > netcoreapp2.2
> > >
> > > > en-US
> > > >
> > > > > **xxx.resources.cs**
> > > > >
> > > > > xxx.resources.dll

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCultureAttribute("en-US")]
```

The project will run but this line will give you an error and won't be recognized.

What I wanted to do is totally eliminate this error everytime that I will build the project.

I'm also thinking that it might be an intellisense error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Solved by disabling parsing of files in `obj/*` folder, by adding exclude patterns in `omnisharp.json` file.

```
  "fileOptions": {
    "systemExcludeSearchPatterns": [
      "**/bin/**/*",
      "**/obj/**/*"
    ]
  }
```

I think this is the right approax, as the `obj` folder is not a part of the project (in terms of source code), but some kind of generates that I perceive as a black-box.

See [Omnisharp configuration documentation](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options) for details.

Comment: It is not a correct answer, I thought it worked, but in the end it did not.